# How to enable Pre deployment stage gates with multi stage yaml pipelines

Tags: azure, yaml

I have a use case where I need to integrate ServiceNow change management as a pre-deployment stage gate. I am able to do it with vNext type pipelines but not multi-stage yaml pipelines. How to achieve this use case ?